# Controlador recibe JSON a nulo

Tags: ajax, json, .net, postman, null

Estoy intentando solventar un problema con mi código pero es imposible. Estoy intentando guardar filas de una matriz. Cada fila tiene un botón y envia en JSON al controlador con el id de la fila asi como un diccionario de string:string. He revisado la petición mostrando en la consola cada uno de los datos y la petición es correcta. Es esta:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.save-effort').forEach(button => {
    console.log('Button found:', button);
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var wpid = this.getAttribute('data-wpid');
        console.log('WPID:', wpid);
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(`.input-effort[data-wpid="${wpid}"]`);
        console.log('Inputs found:', inputs); 
        var efforts = [];

        inputs.forEach(input => {
            var month = input.getAttribute('data-month');
            var value = parseFloat(input.value);
            console.log(`Month: ${month}, Value: ${value}`);

            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                efforts.push({ month, value });
            } else {
                console.error(`Invalid number for month: ${month}, value: ${input.value}`);
            }
        });

        // Muestra los datos recogidos en la consola
        console.log('WPID:', wpid);
        console.log('Efforts array:', efforts);

        if (efforts.length === 0) {
            console.error('No efforts data to send.');
            return; // No realizar la llamada fetch si no hay datos
        }

        // Preparar los datos en el formato que espera el servidor
        var dataToSend = {
            wpId: parseInt(wpid, 10), 
            efforts: efforts.reduce((obj, item) => {
                obj[item.month] = item.value;
                return obj;
            }, {})
        };

        // Muestra el objeto que se enviará en la consola
        console.log('Data to send:', dataToSend);

        // Realizar la llamada AJAX al servidor
        fetch('/Wps/SaveEfforts', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',                        
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.success) {
                    console.log('Efforts saved successfully!');
                } else {
                    console.log('An error occurred while saving efforts:', data.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    });
});
```

El problema es que el metodo del controlador siempre recibe el wpId como 0 y el effort como null. Existe otro metodo en el controlador que tambien recibe los datos como JSON y funciona. Le he pasado los datos por POSTMAN como body de un JSON y pasa lo mismo. wpID a 0 y effort a null. El codigo del controlador es este:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveEfforts(int wpId, [FromBody] Dictionary<string, string> efforts)
{
    // Validar si el WP existe
    var workPackage = await _context.Wps.FindAsync(wpId);
    if (workPackage == null)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "Work Package not found." });
    }

    // Convertir las fechas y esfuerzos a un formato utilizable
    var effortsData = efforts.Select(e => new
    {
        Date = DateTime.ParseExact(e.Key, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Effort = float.Parse(e.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    }).ToList();

    // Lógica para guardar o actualizar los esfuerzos
    foreach (var effortData in effortsData)
    {
        // Verificar si existe un esfuerzo para esa fecha
        var existingEffort = await _context.Projefforts
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(pe => pe.Wp == wpId && pe.Month == effortData.Date);

        if (existingEffort != null)
        {
            // Si existe, actualiza el valor
            existingEffort.Value = (decimal)effortData.Effort;
        }
        else
        {
            // Si no existe, crea uno nuevo
            var newEffort = new Projeffort
            {
                Wp = wpId,
                Month = effortData.Date,
                Value = (decimal)effortData.Effort
            };
            _context.Projefforts.Add(newEffort);
        }
    }

    try
    {
        // Guardar cambios en la base de datos
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Efforts saved successfully." });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Manejar errores de la base de datos aquí
        return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, no tengo manera de solventar esto.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Estas recibiendo mal tu objeto... de ahi el problema...

Answer (score 0):

Vos estas mandando esto:

```
var dataToSend = {
    wpId: parseInt(wpid, 10), 
    efforts: efforts.reduce((obj, item) => {
        obj[item.month] = item.value;
        return obj;
    }, {})
};
```

Pero tu controlador, no esta recibiendo un json con eso, si no que esta esperando:

```
SaveEfforts(int wpId, [FromBody] Dictionary<string, string> efforts)
```

Que no es lo que mandas... porque int wpId es una variable por fuera (y no le estas diciendo al controller de donde tomarla) y el body que espera, no es parseable en base a lo que mandas.

en realidad, deberías recibir y mandar el mismo objeto en los dos casos. Para eso, construí en tu back una interfaz para el json, algo del estilo:

```
public class data
{
    public wpId;
    public Dictionary<string, string> efforts;
}
```

Y recibí en tu controlador ese objeto de la forma:

```
SaveEfforts([FromBody] data MisDatos)
```

Es mas, si controlas la petición, vas a ver que como respuesta, recibís un error de que no puede asignar los valores a cada parte del controller.

---

Mejor que el diccionario, seria mejor recibir una lista, tal que la lista sea de una clase tambien... prueba lo siguiente:

```
public class data
{
    public int wpId;
    public List<MiLista> efforts;
}

public class MiLista
{
    public string fecha;
    public string dato;
}
```

Aunque esto me genera la duda, por como esta armado efforts. Ahi no estoy 100% seguro que lo logre parsear.

Comment: Gracias por contestar compañero. He creado esta clase data para manejar los datos de esta petición, ni que sea para ver que tal funciona el método en cuestión. Le he lanzado la petición por POSTMAN tal que así: {
    "wpId":2605,
    "efforts": {
        "2020-01-01": "0.5",
        "2020-02-01": "0.8"        
    }
} Y sigue igual. ¿Algo más que se te ocurra?

Comment: Prueba sacarle el [FromBody].. luego tambien prueba a mandar las cosas de a una, por ejemplo, envia solo el wpId, saca el diccionario (que realmente no estoy seguro que funcione) y fijate si asi llega. Si el llega, el problema es el diccionario y deberiamos trabajar con el...

Comment: Lo otro que podes hacer es recibir una lista (que seguro funciona mejor) que sea de un tipo especifico (de otra clase) tal que la otra clase tenga 2 propiedades, si queres de tipo string. Eso seguro va a andar mejor.. ya te pongo un ejemplo en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

He decidido trocearlo por aquello que comentas del problema del diccionario. Los datos que van ahora en el body del JSON es únicamente el entero y ni con esas. El problema parece ser es pasarle los datos en el Body del JSON. Si lo paso como parámetro obviamente no tiene ningún problema de lo contrario en este caso del int me lo deja siempre a 0. Debe de haber algún problema en como la aplicación maneja este tipo de datos. Es un MVC en.net 7.0.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).